# numpy array of chars to string

Tags: python, arrays, string, numpy, char

I have a 2D numpy char array (from a NetCDF4 file) which actually represents a list of strings.  I want to convert it into a list of strings.

I know I can use join() to concatenate the chars into a string, but I can only find a way to do this one string at a time:

```
data = np.array([['a','b'],['c','d']])
for row in data[:]:
    print ''.join(row)
```

But it's very slow.  How can I return an array of strings in a single command?  Thanks

Comment: Why are you copying `data` in your for loop?

Answer (score 14):

The list comprehension is the most "pythonic" way.

The most "numpythonic" way would be:

```
>>> data = np.array([['a','b'],['c','d']])
# a 2D view
>>> data.view('S2')
array([['ab'],
       ['cd']], 
      dtype='|S2')
# or maybe a 1D view ...fastest solution:
>>> data.view('S2').ravel()
array(['ab', 'cd'], 
      dtype='|S2')
```

No looping, no list comprehension, not even a copy.  The buffer just sits there unchanged with a different "view" so this is the fastest solution available.

Comment: An important caveat is that the array must be *contiguous* in memory -- otherwise the view fails. You can ensure this by using `data = np.ascontiguousarray(data)`.

Answer (score 4):

Try a list comprehension:

```
>> s = [''.join(row) for row in data]
>> s
['ab', 'cd']
```

which is just your `for` loop rewritten.

Comment: @DavidRobinson Hadn't thought of that - very nice.

Comment: @AdrianR- don't forget to accept his answer (by clicking on the green checkmark) if it answered your question.

Answer (score 2):

```
[row.tostring() for row in data]
```