# Creating a binary representation of whether a string is present or not in a Pandas dataframe

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I have a Pandas dataframe that consists of several columns, the cells of which may or may not contain a string. As an example:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'A':['asfe','eseg','eesg','4dsf','','hdt','gase','gex','gsges','hhbr'],
                   'B':['','bdb','htsdg','','rdshg','th','tjf','','',''],
                   'C':['hrd','jyf','sef','hdsr','','','','','hdts','aseg'],
                   'D':['','','hdts','afse','nfd','','htf','','',''],
                   'E':['','','','','jftd','','','','jfdt','']})
```

...which looks like:

```
       A      B     C     D     E
0   asfe          hrd            
1   eseg    bdb   jyf            
2   eesg  htsdg   sef  hdts      
3   4dsf         hdsr  afse      
4         rdshg         nfd  jftd
5    hdt     th                  
6   gase    tjf         htf      
7    gex                         
8  gsges         hdts        jfdt
9   hhbr         aseg
```

I want to create a column that contains a binary representation of whether the column contains a string or not; as an example, the first row would be represented as 10100.

The only way I can think of doing this is to:

1. Create a scratch dataframe
2. Step through each column detecting whether the cells contain any
   characters and representing as 0/1
3. Concatenate the binary outcomes into a single string
4. Copy column from scratch dataframe back to original.

This is the code I've created:

```
scratchdf = pd.DataFrame().reindex_like(df)

for col in df.columns.values:
    scratchdf[col] = df[col].str.contains(r'\w+',regex = True).astype(int)

scratchdf['bin'] =  scratchdf['A'].astype(str) + \
                    scratchdf['B'].astype(str) + \
                    scratchdf['C'].astype(str) + \
                    scratchdf['D'].astype(str) + \
                    scratchdf['E'].astype(str)

df = df.join(scratchdf['bin'])
```

...which produces the final dataframe:

```
       A      B     C     D     E    bin
0   asfe          hrd              10100
1   eseg    bdb   jyf              11100
2   eesg  htsdg   sef  hdts        11110
3   4dsf         hdsr  afse        10110
4         rdshg         nfd  jftd  01011
5    hdt     th                    11000
6   gase    tjf         htf        11010
7    gex                           10000
8  gsges         hdts        jfdt  10101
9   hhbr         aseg              10100
```

This works but seems a bit wasteful (especially with large dataframes). Is there a way to create the binary representation column directly, without needing to create a scratch dataframe?

Comment: I edited my answer and gained some more speedup.  Let you know in case you need it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check empty string or convert to `bool` first, then convert to `int`, `str` and last `join` or `sum`:

```
df['new'] = (df != '').astype(int).astype(str).apply(''.join, axis=1)

#faster alternative
df['new'] = (df != '').astype(int).astype(str).values.sum(axis=1)

print (df)

       A      B     C     D     E    new
0   asfe          hrd              10100
1   eseg    bdb   jyf              11100
2   eesg  htsdg   sef  hdts        11110
3   4dsf         hdsr  afse        10110
4         rdshg         nfd  jftd  01011
5    hdt     th                    11000
6   gase    tjf         htf        11010
7    gex                           10000
8  gsges         hdts        jfdt  10101
9   hhbr         aseg              10100
```

**Timings**:

```
df = pd.concat([df] * 1000, ignore_index=True)

In [99]: %timeit df.astype(bool).astype(int).astype(str).values.sum(axis=1)
10 loops, best of 3: 155 ms per loop

In [100]: %timeit (df != '').astype(int).astype(str).values.sum(axis=1)
10 loops, best of 3: 158 ms per loop

In [101]: %timeit (df != '').astype(int).astype(str).apply(''.join, axis=1)
1 loop, best of 3: 330 ms per loop

In [102]: %timeit df.astype(bool).astype(int).astype(str).apply(''.join, axis=1)
1 loop, best of 3: 326 ms per loop

In [103]: %timeit df.astype(bool).astype(int).apply(lambda row: ''.join(str(i) for i in row), axis=1)
1 loop, best of 3: 210 ms per loop
```

Comment: Thanks very much for that answer. Very helpful indeed, especially the different timings for the suggested approaches.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the fact that empty strings correspond to False and non-empty to True. So casting the string dataframe to bool gives a dataframe as true and false. Recasting this to int converts true to 1 and false to 0, then just apply a join operation across rows:

```
df['binary'] = df.astype(bool).astype(int).apply(
    lambda row: ''.join(str(i) for i in row), axis=1)
print(df)
```

result:

```
       A      B     C     D     E  binary
0   asfe          hrd              10100
1   eseg    bdb   jyf              11100
2   eesg  htsdg   sef  hdts        11110
3   4dsf         hdsr  afse        10110
4         rdshg         nfd  jftd  01011
5    hdt     th                    11000
6   gase    tjf         htf        11010
7    gex                           10000
8  gsges         hdts        jfdt  10101
9   hhbr         aseg              10100
```

edit: just realized another user posted basically the same thing (also fixed copy error)

Here's another way using generators:

```
def iterable_to_binary_mask(iterable):
    bools = (bool(i) for i in iterable)
    ints = (int(i) for i in bools)
    strs = (str(i) for i in ints)
    return ''.join(strs)

df['binary'] = df.apply(iterable_to_binary_mask, axis=1)
```

This is about 3 times slower than the type conversion approach on my machine but should use
minimal memory.

Comment: Thanks very much for the solution. The answers from your and from @jezreal were both very useful. I selected the answer from jezreal as the accepted answer because of the timings showing how different components  compared but I up-voted your answer as well as it provided a valid answer to the question.

Comment: Just noticed my typo: @jezrael. Sorry.

Answer (score 1):

**Method 1**

```
a = np.where(df != "", "1", "0").astype("|S1")
df["bin"] = np.apply_along_axis(lambda x: x.tostring().decode("utf-8"), 1, a)
```

**Method 2**

```
df["bin"] = np.append(
               np.where(df != "", "1", "0").astype("S1"), 
               np.array([["\n"]]).astype("S1").repeat(df.shape[0], axis=0), 
               axis=1
            ).tostring().decode("utf-8")[:-1].split("\n")
```

Method 2 appends `\n` to the end of the numpy array

```
array([[b'1', b'0', b'1', b'0', b'0', b'\n'],
       [b'1', b'1', b'1', b'0', b'0', b'\n'],
       [b'1', b'1', b'1', b'1', b'0', b'\n'],
       ...,
       [b'1', b'0', b'0', b'0', b'0', b'\n'],
       [b'1', b'0', b'1', b'0', b'1', b'\n'],
       [b'1', b'0', b'1', b'0', b'0', b'\n']], dtype='|S1')
```

Then call `tostring` and `decode`. Remove the last "\n" and then split by "\n".

**Method 3** (Using `view` Reference: [numpy array of chars to string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10984471/numpy-array-of-chars-to-string))

```
np.ascontiguousarray(
    np.where(df != "", "1", "0").astype("S1")
).view('|S5').astype(str)
```

### Timings:

```
(Based on jezrael's setup df = pd.concat([df] * 1000, ignore_index=True))

# method 2
%timeit np.append(np.where(df != "", "1", "0").astype("S1"), np.array([["\n"]]).astype("S1").repeat(df.shape[0], axis=0), axis=1).tostring().decode("utf-8")[:-1].split("\n")
12.3 ms ± 175 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)
# method 3
%timeit np.ascontiguousarray(np.where(df != "", "1", "0").astype("S1")).view('|S5').astype(str)
12.8 ms ± 164 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)
# method 1 (slower)
%timeit np.apply_along_axis(lambda x: x.tostring().decode("utf-8"), 1, np.where(df != "", "1", "0").astype("S1"))
45 ms ± 1.86 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)
```

Replicated experiments of jezrael's.

```
In [99]: %timeit df.astype(bool).astype(int).astype(str).values.sum(axis=1)
28.9 ms ± 782 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)
In [100]: %timeit (df != '').astype(int).astype(str).values.sum(axis=1)
29 ms ± 645 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)
In [101]: %timeit (df != '').astype(int).astype(str).apply(''.join, axis=1)
168 ms ± 2.93 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)
In [102]: %timeit df.astype(bool).astype(int).astype(str).apply(''.join, axis=1)
173 ms ± 7.36 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)
In [103]: %timeit df.astype(bool).astype(int).apply(lambda row: ''.join(str(i) for i in row), axis=1)
159 ms ± 3.05 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)
```

Comment: Thanks for all the work you've put into answering the question. I always forget to look at the options available in numpy but this answer shows there can be some very real time and efficiency benefits. Very cool indeed.

Comment: @user1718097 no problem. Interesting problem :P

Comment: But just noticed that the output is producing 01011 rather than 10100; I think the .where() method should be np.where(df != "", "1","0") instead :-)